# Why is node ios_setup.js [App ID] [App Name] causing an error?

Tags: ios, node.js, facebook, react-native

I am using the FB instructions for setting up FB login in my React Native that can be found here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/getting-started
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-ios

I am moseying along very well in the instructions until I get to the instruction to do this at my command line:

```
node ios_setup.js [App ID] [App Name]
```

But this causes the following error:

```
fs.js:895
  return binding.mkdir(pathModule._makeLong(path),
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'ios/Frameworks/'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:895:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/markkeane/Documents/FBTest/ios/ios_setup.js:38:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:423:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:147:9)
```

I have no idea what this means or how to resolve it. I tried installing ionic again but that did not help. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

I had the problem today and I realized that I should have run

> node ios_setup.js [App ID] [App Name]

In `root folder` not in `ios` folder

Comment: root folder is iOS ?

Comment: No, root folder is one level above. Where the src and node_modules folder lives

Answer (score 0):

For quick solution, manually update the ios_setup.js code.

from

`var plistDirPath = '';`

to

`var plistDirPath = './ios/{YourProjectName}';`

this should tell the js to locate the correct Info.plist